# Ad hoc enable/disable "click sound" with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, browser

Using `div` as a custom button with `onclick` event I want to be able turn on/off browser "click sound".

```
$(".button").click(function(e)
{
  if ($(this).attr("disabled") !== "disabled")
  {
    // my code
  }
  else
  {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

I tried to use `preventDefault`, but it does not disable sound and browser play "click sound" anyway. How can I manage this default browser feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't turn off this sound. `.preventDefault()` stops the default action on the button (e.g postback/follow link/etc). The "click sound" is not part of your site but rather a browser/OS feature. You have no control over this.